# LateInitializationError when testing

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

My variable has been initialized but I still get `LateInitializationError`. I only get this during testing, it works fine normally.
Logs:

```
Closure: () => void from Function 'updateLight':. // This is the value of variable being printed

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following LateError was thrown while handling a gesture:
LateInitializationError: Field 'updateMethod' has not been initialized.
```

I can print the variable which is to be used, which means it has been initialized.

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example?  Is the *same* test printing the value and triggering the exception?  Are you certain that the `updateMethod` member isn't being printed from one object but the `LateInitializationError` is being triggered by a different object?

Comment: Yes @jamesdlin, just checked. So, `updateMethod`'s value was printed from another object. I am testing with multiple values, so I am using for loop to check with multiple values. When I remove the for loop, and check with just one value, I don't get the error. But they are all the same objects.

Comment: If I check with different values with individual tests, they all work fine. But when using them inside for loop, I get the error.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say the objects are both different and the same. Anyway,  nobody can tell you what you're doing wrong without reproduction details or psychic powers.  If you're initializing some `late` variable asynchronously, that's a terrible idea and is a recipe for `LateInitializationError`s.  And/or you have a race condition that is exposed by the test.